# Rails & Nginx Delete request - 405 Not Allowed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, unicorn

I'm only getting this error on my production server. It will only return a '405 Not Allowed' when I do a 'Delete' request method and it should return with some UJS. It works fine on my development machine.

Below is the code I'm using within my view. This will then return some JS.

```
link_to("Delete", image, method: :delete, remote: true, data: {confirm: "Are you Sure?"})
```

The link at the bottom is where I've got my nginx configuration as I'm using there capistrano tasks. I've googled around to see what could fix the issue but a lot I've found are over 3 years old and don't seem to do anything. For example: http://andre.arko.net/2011/06/30/rails-page-caching-nginx-and-restful-apis/

Any ideas would be great as I'm currently lost. My server configuration is: Ubuntu 12.04, Unicorn, Nginx, Rails 4, Ruby 2.

https://github.com/kalys/capistrano-nginx-unicorn/blob/master/lib/generators/capistrano/nginx_unicorn/templates/nginx_conf.erb

Answer (score 0):

i recommend cleaning up the NGINX file by removing the IF statements and doing 301 redirects instead.  After that take care of the error page logic in your application, if you want to keep the error page logic, move it in to your server block.  Here is my working nginx.conf as an example.

https://gist.github.com/Austio/6399964

Comment: I've tried removing the if statements but still getting the same response. Do you have any other ideas? I've just uploaded my nginx.conf to gist as well - https://gist.github.com/petermumford/8442888

Comment: I found the problem `location ~ ^/(assets|images|javascripts|stylesheets|swfs|system)/ {` should be `location ^~ /(assets|images|javascripts|stylesheets|swfs|system)/ {` All I did was change the `~^`. Hopefully this was a typo or maybe there is a reason why it was like that? @Austio, do you know?

Comment: Good eye, ~^ is not an nginx location syntax option but ^~ is.  http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location